# Ubuntu 13.10 and lampp : PHP path issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, path, laravel-4, lampp

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and Lampp.
When I try to run :

```
 sudo php artisan job-daemon
```

I get : `Laravel requires mCrypt PHP extension.`

But when I run :

```
php artisan job-daemon
```

it works just fine..

`php -m` gives me the following:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar


.
.
.
.

mcrypt


.
.
.
.
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

`which php` gives me :

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php
```

while `sudo which php` gives me

```
/usr/bin/php
```

I have edited the ~./bashrc as following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/php
```

I have already asked in Ubuntu forums but still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

The question is why do you use lampp on Ubuntu? Why you don't use the apt package manager?

I think your system has installed PHP over the package manager. Thats why you get another Path with sudo. You have set the Path for your user but not for root (sudo).

So you could try to install the missing package over the package manager with

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

If you need some more packages you can search with the following command

```
sudo apt-cache search php
```

then you get all packages with php in the package name.

Comment: lampp has the advantage that with one command I start apache mysql and other services..Since I have lampp installed I would like to help me change the sudo php path...Is that possible..?

Comment: Change the user to root `su` then add the path in the .bashrc from the admin or use the php5-cli package.